# Unable to mount flash drive or SD/SDHC card in Device/dev/sdf* already mounted at '/media/usb*'

Tags: 12.10, usb, nautilus, mount, sd-card

But when I look in the Home folder they show up in the left hand section and I have full access.  It looks like I have caused an unintended consequence in trying to find solutions to an earlier problem with the card reader (now fixed).

When I click to dis-mount usb stick or SD/SDHC card I am asked to supply my admin password!

Do I need to fix this situation?  If yes, how?

Thank you

njsg, Terminal output as requested and thank you for your patience,

With usb stick in multi-card reader,

```
roger@roger-desktop:~$ mount
/dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/roger/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=roger)
/dev/sdf1 on /media/usb0 type vfat (rw,noexec,nodev,sync,noatime,nodiratime)
roger@roger-desktop:~$

roger@roger-desktop:~$ dmesg | grep sdf
[  218.603341] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] 7806976 512-byte logical blocks: (3.99 GB/3.72 GiB)
[  218.604450] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Write Protect is off
[  218.604455] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[  218.605449] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] No Caching mode page present
[  218.605453] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  218.610441] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] No Caching mode page present
[  218.610448] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  218.637917]  sdf: sdf1
[  218.643388] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] No Caching mode page present
[  218.643396] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  218.643401] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI removable disk
roger@roger-desktop:~$
```

With usb stick and SDHC card in multi-card reader,

```
roger@roger-desktop:~$ mount
/dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/roger/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=roger)
/dev/sdf1 on /media/usb0 type vfat (rw,noexec,nodev,sync,noatime,nodiratime)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/usb1 type vfat (rw,noexec,nodev,sync,noatime,nodiratime)
roger@roger-desktop:~$



roger@roger-desktop:~$ dmesg | grep sdf
[  218.603341] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] 7806976 512-byte logical blocks: (3.99 GB/3.72 GiB)
[  218.604450] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Write Protect is off
[  218.604455] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[  218.605449] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] No Caching mode page present
[  218.605453] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  218.610441] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] No Caching mode page present
[  218.610448] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  218.637917]  sdf: sdf1
[  218.643388] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] No Caching mode page present
[  218.643396] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  218.643401] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI removable disk
roger@roger-desktop:~$
```

Note, where sdf appears in square brackets above it is RED in Terminal.

For both the usb stick and SDHC card I can read and copy to my PC, but I can not write from PC to them.  Using Ubuntu Home Folder, Devices, Properties both have msdos file systems.  When I plug them into a Windows XP laptop they are both FAT32 file system.  Does that mean that Ubuntu sees FAT32 as msdos?

Comment: How did you mount it? Which solutions are you talking about? (Un)mounting in UNIX filesystems requires root privileges unless 1) the filesystem is in `/etc/fstab` and 2) it explicitly has an option allowing any user (or maybe a specific user?) to mount it. There are, although, several tools to bypass this limitation, like `gvfs` and `pmount`. It'd help if we knew what exactly did you use.

Comment: I now wish I had a record of exactly what I did do.  I did install 'Input-utils' via Synaptic Package Manager and listed Medibuntu in Software Sources.

Comment: njsg, I could not provide a copy of the content of /etc/fstab here as it is '187 characters too long'!  In the file 'media' there are files for usb0 through to usb7.  There is nothing in file 'mnt'.  The PC is a desktop that I assembled years ago, now with 12.10 64bit installed and an internal usb connected multi card reader.  When I plug in a USB stick the error message is 'Unable to mount FLASH DRIVE Device/dev/sdf1 is already mounted at '/media/usb0'.  However the FLASH DRIVE is listed under 'Devices' on lefthand side of 'Home Folder'.

Comment: njsg.  Now I can not copy files to the FLASH DRIVE. The error message is 'There was an error copying the file into /media/usb0. Error opening file '/media/usb0/Items for 23 Haddon.odt': Permission denied'.  I am still able to copy files from the FLASH DRIVE to my PC.  Do I need to back-up all of my data and do a fresh re-install?

Comment: From what you describe, there is something automounting your flash drive. I don't know if this is usual for Ubuntu, but I'd not be surprised if it were. Now, which filesystem is that flash drive using? Are you *sure* it can be mounted read-write in that computer? Please provide the output of `mount` in the question, especially the line with `/dev/sdf1` (it *will* be there, the error means the partition has already been mounted, no dark magic there), and also the output of `dmesg | grep sdf`, which will likely contain error messages if the problem is a corrupt filesystem.

Comment: The `input-utils` thing is most likely unrelated. Has this pendrive ever worked with this system before?

Comment: njsg, The pen drive has worked many times with this system, but the SDHC card was used once only with this system.  Earlier this evening I completely removed the package usbmount using Synaptic, having seen it as an issue in another Question.  Now I can read and write to my pen drives and SD/SDHC cards again.  Thank you for your straight and open assistance.  Ubuntu still reports them as msdos, but in XP they are FAT32 file system!